# difference in list.append and list addition in class instances

Tags: python, list, append, instance

I wish I could better title the question. 
Anyway,
Here is test.py

```
class test(object):
    tags = []
    def __init__(self):
       self.tags= self.tags + ['tag']

testA= test()
testB = test()

print testA.tags
```

Here is the output:

> ['tag']

Now I change class test to

```
class test(object):
    tags = []
    def __init__(self):
        self.tags.append('tag')
```

Here is the output:

> ['tag', 'tag']

I expected the first result `['tag']` in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.tags + ['tag']` creates a **new** object. And then it is assigned to `self.tags`.

`self.tags.append` works with the same `tags` object from the class. So all the objects share the same `tags` object and append to it.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the class variable `tags` variable is not needed or useful here. Just set `self.tags = ["tag"]` (or some other appropriate value) in `__init__` and you're home free.